# How to add an list item to an existing list of items in D3?

Tags: d3.js

Newbie here. I am trying to add an `li` to an existing list but not getting expected result. I would like to add it to the end of list.

```
   ... 
   <ul id="items">
       <li class="item">One</li>
       <li class="item">Two</li>
       <li class="item">Three</li>
       <li class="item">Four</li>
       <li class="item">Five</li>
    </ul>
    ...
```

In console

```
d3.selectAll('li')
   .data([1,2,3,4,5,6])
   .enter()
   .append('li')
   .text('a text')
   .classed('item',true);
```

This adds `li` to the end of `body`

```
...
</body>
<li class="item">a text</li>
...
```

Update:

Did a bit of experiment and got a working one. However, need to understand why the earlier one didn't work?

```
d3.select('#items')
   .selectAll('.item')
   .data([1,2,3,4,5,6])
   .enter()
   .append('li')
   .text('a text')
   .classed('item',true);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your first attempt you weren't providing D3 with an element to append to so it just appended to the end of the document. By selecting `ul#items` and then appending to it you were successful in adding one additional `li` as you bound your `data` array to all `li` children of `ul#items`. As you only had 5 `li` items and 6 items in your `data` array the `enter()` method was called which appended an extra `li`. Try this code and consider what is happening:

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5];

function updateData(data) {
  var item = d3.select('#items')
    .selectAll('li')
    .data(data);

// Enter
  item
    .enter()
    .append('li')
    .attr('class', 'item')
    .text(function(d) { return 'List item ' + d });

// Update
  item
    .text(function(d) { return 'Updated value to' + d });

// Exit
  item.exit().remove();
}

updateData(data);

setTimeout(function() {
  var newData = data.map(function(v) {
    return v * 2;
  });

  updateData(newData)
}, 3000);

setTimeout(function() {
  var newData = data.concat(data);

  updateData(newData)
}, 6000);

setTimeout(function() {

  updateData(data)
}, 9000);
```

We can select the `ul#items` and bound `data` to it. When `updateData` is called D3 will assess whether there are more dom elements than data elements and choose whether to call `enter()` or `exit()` accordingly. We also have an update procedure (to change the text to the new value it has been given). Hopefully this explains the nature of what you were experiencing. Have a good read about enter, update, exit in D3. Once you've understood that you can really do a lot of complex stuff with ease.